# How to decrypt a .doc/docx file with Apache POI?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-poi

I am trying to open a password protected .doc file using Apache POI. However, I am getting the error.

> org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException: Cannot process encrypted word file

Can anyone help me in solving this. 
I will be thankful if I can get the code.

Comment: @MWiesner: Editing the question until it fits to your answer?

Answer (score 3):

An `EncryptedDocumentException` signals that you are trying to process an encrypted document which was not previously "unlocked".

The following code snippet is suitable to check if this is the case for XML-based formats (*.xlsx, .pptx, .docx, ...*) so that you can process it safely later on:

```
String password = "secret"; // set password
File fileToProcess; // obtain/read/open the file here....
NPOIFSFileSystem filesystem  = new NPOIFSFileSystem(fileToProcess);
EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(filesystem);
Decryptor d = Decryptor.getInstance(info);

try {
    if (!d.verifyPassword(password)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to process: document is encrypted");
    }

    InputStream dataStream = d.getDataStream(filesystem);

    // parse dataStream as the document is now processable from here on
    // ...

} catch (GeneralSecurityException ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to process encrypted document", ex);
}
```

The above example is taken from [encryption section of the official POI documentation](http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html) and was modified according to the project's JavaDoc. You might want to check/read the JavaDoc of the classes [`Decryptor`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/poifs/crypt/Decryptor.html) and/or [`NPOIFSFileSystem`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/NPOIFSFileSystem.html).

In case you want to convert binary file formats (*.xls, .ppt, .doc, ...*), check the *encryption section* for code examples.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question initially  was about decrypting the binary `*.doc` format:

The code in [Apache POI - Encryption support Binary formats](http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html#Binary+formats) needs  to be updated a little bit for using with `HWPF`. [HWPFDocument](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/HWPFDocument.html#HWPFDocument-org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem-) cannot be created from `NPOIFSFileSystem`. There `POIFSFileSystem` is needed. But else it is the same.

Having a `file.doc` encrypted using password "pass", after this code had run the new file `fileDecrypted.doc` is decrypted and can be opened without a password.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.record.crypto.Biff8EncryptionKey;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;

public class ReadEncryptedHWPF {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword("pass"); 
  POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream("file.doc")); 
  HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);
  Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword(null);
  doc.write(new FileOutputStream("fileDecrypted.doc"));
  doc.close();

  doc = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("fileDecrypted.doc"));
  org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor extractor = new org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor(doc);
  System.out.println(extractor.getText());
  extractor.close();

 }
}
```